# Access eloquent relationships when return object as json

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am currently building a JSON RESTful API with Laravel/Lumen and now trying to access model attributes that are being stored in the relationship of this model

```
// I also want to return User->roles
return User::find(1)->first();
```

Returns:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "email": '...'
}
```

I actually found a way but that seems pretty much hacked and not clean

```
    // Get user
    $user = User::find($id)->first();

    // Make roles public
    $user->roles = $user->roles;

    // Return object
    return $user;
```

Returns:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "email": '...',
  "roles": [
  ...
  ]
}
```

Is there a better way? Or is this kind of a security thing where you want to protect your data? But since you can access the relationship in php why shouldn't it be returned as json object?

Couldn't find something in the laravel documentation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can in your relationship use the helper function `with` like so as:

```
user::find($id)->with('roles')->first()
```

Comment: Did I missed this one in the documentation? Seeing this the first time, thanks!

Comment: @Flyde depending on which version you use, it's right here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-with have a nice day! :-)

Comment: If you want use with in all querys, yo can fill property $with in UserModel.class. 
| protected $with = ['roles'];

Answer (score 4):

```
public function show(User $user) {
        return $user->load('books');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest syntax for this will be:

```
User::with('roles')->find($id);
```

There's no need to use `first()` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user = User::with('roles')->where('id',  $id)->first();
```